# How to deal with time delay conflicts?

Tags: python, asynchronous

I'm still an amateur programmer and just trying to understand how to approach this problem. I'm writing in Python.

I have input that is constantly being updated at all times (continuous stream). As it comes in, I run a for loop on the newest entry that verifies if a series of conditions are met. If so, then the program needs to wait for 5 minutes before executing the next action on that piece of input. But it also need to keep checking the rest of the inputs.

So, pseudocode:

```
inputs = continous_stream_of_input
for input in inputs:
    if conditions == True:
        wait 5 minutes
        do next action
```

but this block needs to be run on each piece of input that comes in, as soon as it comes in (without the 5 minute delay). How should I proceed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That looks like the perfect place for a timer from the threading module:

```
import threading

# It can take whatever args you want.
def do_action(a, b, c):
   # It can do whatever you want.

inputs = continuous_stream_of_input
for input in inputs:
    if conditions:
        # 5 minutes is 300 seconds.     args is, again, whatever you want.
        threading.Timer(300, do_action, args=(a, b, c)).start()
```